# How to capture word in Python

Tags: python

I would like to capture word, in Python, when I have several links.

But only capture the number after `i`. how can I perform that?

Below i put two example links:

```
txt = "https://www.amazn.com.my/products/honor-play-4gb64gb-rom-original-i409297194-s592754043.html?spm=a2o4k."
txt2 = 'https://www.amazn.com.my/products/oneplus-6-a6000-64gb128gb256gb-original-imported-set-global-rom-available-in-all-colour-now-i355104077-s592325529.html?spm=a2o4k.'
x = txt.split("-")
print(x)
```

I know there is a function .split but it just returns like this when print(x)

```
['https://www.amazon.com.my/products/honor', 'play', '4gb64gb', 'rom', 'original', 'i409297194', 's592754043.html?spm=a2o4k.']
```

My awaited result should be like this when print(x):

```
409297194
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the string which starts with "i" and replace it:

```
def getIString(text):
    for i in text: 
        if i[0] == "i" and i[1:].isdigit():
            print i.replace("i","")


txt = "https://www.amazn.com.my/products/honor-play-4gb64gb-rom-original-i409297194-s592754043.html?spm=a2o4k."
txt2 = 'https://www.amazn.com.my/products/oneplus-6-a6000-64gb128gb256gb-original-imported-set-global-rom-available-in-all-colour-now-i355104077-s592325529.html?spm=a2o4k.'
x = txt.split("-")
y = txt2.split("-")

getIString(x)
getIString(y)
```

You have to check if a number comes after the "i", otherwise the "imported" is also taken

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[print(item) for item in x if item[0]=='i' and item[1:].isnumeric()]
```

it checks if the list item starts with the letter `'i'` and the rest of it is numeric

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnum'

Comment: sorry i wasn't paying attention this should work, changed `isnum` to `isnumeric`

Answer (score 0):

I see in both examples you have there are numbers that [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) the letter `i`. I'd use that to your advantage and write your own function to find this number.

```
txt = "https://www.amazn.com.my/products/honor-play-4gb64gb-rom-original-i409297194-s592754043.html?spm=a2o4k."

def find_num(text):
    try:
        return next(iter([t for t in text.split('-') if t.startswith('i') and t[1:].isnum()]))
    except StopIteration:
        return None

#then just use:
print(find_num(txt))
```